# Which probability distribution should I use to get unconditional PDF?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Here is my question.

I want to get the unconditional PDF of a random variable t with PDF $f(t\mid\tau_1,\tau_2,\dots,\tau_n)$. Depending on the relation between $\tau_1,\tau_2,\dots,\tau_n$, I have two choices. One is that, when $\tau_1=\tau_2=\cdots=\tau_n$, I have $f_1(t\mid\tau_1,\tau_2,\dots,\tau_n)$. The other is that, when $\tau_i \neq \tau_j, i \neq j$, I have $f_2(t\mid\tau_1,\tau_2,\dots,\tau_n)$.

Which one should I choose to get the unconditional PDF of $t$, when I use 
$f(t) = \int\cdots\int f(t\mid\tau_1,\tau_2,\dots,\tau_n)\,d\tau_1d\,\tau_2\cdots d\tau_n$?

I have tried $f_2$, since it seems more general, but the analysis result does not match the simulation result well. So could some one offer me some suggestions?

Thanks so much!.

Comment: What if $\tau_1=\tau_2\ne\tau_3$?

Comment: That is exactly the cases I am worried about. Maybe there is no way to get the true answer to this question